# Leave main ui-view the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I figure there's got to be a way to do this, but I wasn't able to figure it out. I'm trying to add a sidebar view to my application and thought it would be really slick if I could do the sidebar as a `ui-view`. The problem I'm having though is I don't want to specify every possible sidebar view for every single page. I'd like to be able to just set the view in the sidebar and leave the current/main view the same.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dangeruponu/1ko5pw7c/1/) demonstrates my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved this problem by introducing a new abstract base state `site`, which contains two *named* views `content` (main area) and `sidebar`. In the content area we exchange the template depending on which state we are in. The sidebar is not affected by changing the content states.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        url: '/',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            content: {
                template: ''
            },
            sidebar: {
                template: '<div>this is the sidebar but I also want to see page1 or page2</div>'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('page1', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '1',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                template: '<div>This is page 1</div>'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('page2', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '2',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                template: '<div>This is page 2</div>'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72283p2z/) for a demonstration.

If you want to use multiple independent views, you should have a look at [ui-router-extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home) as ui-router does not support parallel states, but just a state tree. [This blog entry](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/11/setting-up-individual-views-with-ui-router-and-ui-router-extras/) discusses the problem and provides a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bEdJczNwYEfTI7joyh9h?p=preview).

Comment: And how do I change the sidebar without changing the content? See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/dangeruponu/74k1bmkj/